# Python: Appending to a nested list using for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I am trying to create a simple for-loop to append a float to a nested list.

```
base = [[],[],[],[]]           # [h,T,rho,sos]
top  = [[],[],[],[]]

for i in range(4):                              # Select h,T,rho,sos
    for j in range(len(marstable)-1):           # Append data to sublist
        base[i].append(float(marstable[j][i]))
    top[i] = base[i][1:] + [float(marstable[-1][i])]
```

marstable is defined in a previous function, and is also a nested list. I keep getting an error "IndexError: list index out of range" for line

```
base[i].append(float(marstable[j][i]))
```

Why do I get this and what is the best way to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does every list in `marstable` have at least 4 elements? I would try to post your full code.

Comment: Check the second dimension of `marstable`, is it possible that somewhere it is smaller than 4?

Answer (score -1):

```
base = [[],[],[],[]]
top  = [[],[],[],[]]
for i in range(4):
   for j in range(len(marstable)-1):
         base[i].append(float(marstable[i][j]))
   top[i] = base[i][1:] + [float(marstable[i][-1])]
```